# jQuery UI autocomplete + CakePHP

Tags: jquery, json, cakephp, autocomplete

I'm setting up jQuery UI autocomplete on a CakePHP site, and feel like I'm missing something really obvious, but it's almost working...

So the simple jQuery code is:

```
$(function() {
    $("#SearchQuery").autocomplete({
        source: "<?= $session->base ?>/search/complete",
        minLength: 2
    });
});
```

This connects to my search controller, and the search controller returns items from the database. I can get the results back if I don't try to actually look at the "term" (what has been typed. So, in my controller this works:

```
function complete(){
    $entries = $this->Entry->find('list');
    $this->set('entries', $entries);
}
```

It is returned as JSON, and drops down from the input like it should. But it never narrows the results based on what has been typed. I would think that this should narrow the results:

```
function complete($query = null){
    $entries = $this->Entry->find('list', 
        array('conditions' => array('title LIKE' => '%'.$query.'%')));
    $this->set('entries', $entries);
}
```

But with this code nothing is ever returned. What am I doing wrong?

**P.S.** People who find this question and are having trouble getting the results back to the autocomplete function, be sure you're returning properly formatted JSON results: http://www.pagebakers.nl/2007/06/05/using-json-in-cakephp-12/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple, as expected... "term" is passed as `$_GET['term']`, so it's not available from the controller function's variables. (Why I thought it would be passed as a URL segment I have no idea...)

This works:

```
function complete(){
    $query = $_GET['term'];

    $entries = $this->Entry->find('list', 
        array('conditions' => array('title LIKE' => '%'.$query.'%')));
    $this->set('entries', $entries);
}
```

Comment: It's available. use: $this->params['url']['term']; :-)

Comment: yeah. this is one of those cases where i'm not sure what the advantage is of using `$this->params['url']` vs. `$_GET`. is it safer somehow?

Comment: If it's just a query for a drop down, I don't think security is too much of an issue. If it concerns you, though, you can clean up the term with standard php before you act on it.